# How to disable carousel in v-tabs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm doing kind of horizontal navigation bar using `v-tabs` and `v-tabs-items` to switch between slides by clicking on the specific tab.

But Vuetify automatically adds carousel to `v-tabs` component. How can I disable it? I need to make `v-tabs` component multilined.

I tried to add `v-tab` inside `v-item-group`, but it loose all it's styles. Also, `hide-slider` didn't disable slider too.

```html
<v-tabs v-model="tab" hide-slider>
  <v-tab v-for="(item, index) of [1, 2, 3, ..., 100]" :key="index">
    {{ item }}
  </v-tab>
</v-tabs>
```

I should render elements like on this [picture](https://wiki.jenkins.io/download/attachments/46336202/MultiRowTabBar.png?version=1&modificationDate=1285959435000&api=v2). If it haven't enought space to for element on current line - it should add it on next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.v-tabs-bar__content {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
div.v-tabs-bar {
  height: auto;
}
```

... will, most likely, solve your problem.

See it working:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    items: [...Array(100).keys()].map(() => ['anything', 'whatever', 'something'][Math.floor(3 * Math.random())]),
  }),
  propsData: {
    tab: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    }
  }  
})
```

```css
.v-tabs-bar__content {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
div.v-tabs-bar {
  height: auto;
}
div.v-tab {
  line-height: 3rem; /* or use padding instead */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@3.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.0.15/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.0.15/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-tabs>
    <v-tab v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
      {{item}}
    </v-tab>
</v-tabs>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good, but with one issue: line of selected tab is rendered at the bottom of entire box. 
https://codepen.io/PowerSlime/pen/JjPLpZp

But, it's easy to fix. Thank you!